# Generating PDF Invoices for Products using Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, pdf

Hey Flutter Developers can you help me pleases
Im trying to generate a pdf invoice here is the code[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8KMY.png)

```
Future<void> generateInvoice(List<Product> products) async {
    final pdf = pw.Document();
    final font = await rootBundle.load('assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf');
    final ttf = pw.Font.ttf(font);

    final headers = ['Product Name', 'Price', 'Quantity'];
    final tableHeaders = headers
        .map(
          (header) => pw.Text(
            header,
            style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf),
          ),
        )
        .toList();
    final headerRow = pw.TableRow(children: tableHeaders);

    final tableRows = products.map((product) {
      final rowData = [
        pw.Text(product.name, style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf)),
        pw.Text(product.price.toString(), style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf)),
        pw.Text(product.quantity.toString(), style: pw.TextStyle(font: ttf)),
      ];
      return pw.TableRow(children: rowData);
    }).toList();

    pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return pw.Container(
            child: pw.Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: pw.CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                pw.Text(
                  'Invoice',
                  style: pw.TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    font: ttf,
                  ),
                ),
                pw.SizedBox(height: 20),
                pw.Table(
                  border: pw.TableBorder.all(),
                  children: [headerRow, ...tableRows],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );

    final appDocumentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final filePath = '${appDocumentsDir.path}/invoice.pdf';
    final file = File(filePath);
    await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());

    OpenFile.open(filePath);
  }
```

````
Widget _showInvoiceButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: AppColors.appBarColor,
      ),
      onPressed: () async {
        final appDocumentsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final filePath = '${appDocumentsDir.path}/invoice.pdf';
        final file = File(filePath);

        if (await file.exists()) {
          OpenFile.open(filePath);
        } else {
          // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Invoice not found'),
                content: const Text('Please generate the invoice first.'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('OK'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }
      },
      child: const Text(
        'Show Invoice',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSubmitButton() {
    return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: AppColors.appBarColor),
      onPressed: () async {
        try {
          await generateInvoice(products);
          // setState(() {
          //   products.clear();
          //   discountPercent = 0.0;
          // });
        } catch (e, stackTrace) {
          print('Error generating invoice: $e');
          print('Stack trace: $stackTrace');
        }
      },
      child: const Text(
        'Submit',
        style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
      ),
    );
  }```



Im expecting to generate a pdf invoice
````

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.